# Bash function with arguments

Tags: linux, bash

I want to create a bash command to update automatically a file from my public dropbox to my local machine.

for instance:
the file on my local /home/john/Directory1/file1.dat is also located on my dropbox cloud and accessible using the link: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/xxxxxx/Directory1/file1.dat

[BTW, it means Directory1/ is a directory at the root of my public/ dropbox directory]. So I would like to create a function called MyNewFunction:

```
cd /home/john/Directory1/
MyNewFunction file1.dat
```

and MyNewFunction will execute:

```
wget -N https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/xxxxxx/Directory1/file1.dat
```

[-N is set to update and overwrite file1.dat]

therefore, I need to select the current directory name "Directory1" to create the https link

Comment: the pwd command?  Its not enirely clear what the question is

Comment: doesn't just installing dropbox on your machine and turning on auto sync solve this ? why would you want a bash script for something dropbox desktop application can do it ?

Comment: @sa77, dropbox is not allowed in my server... but yes that would have been easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full path of the current directory is in the `PWD` variable. You can use bash's string manipulation to get only the name of the current directory:

```
dir=${PWD##*/}
```

Then, since `file1.dat` is the first argument:

```
wget -N "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/xxxxxx/${dir}/$1"
```

So, the function would be:

```
MyNewFunction () {
    local dir=${PWD##*/}
    wget -N "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/xxxxxx/${dir}/$1"
}
```

Or:

```
MyNewFunction () {
    wget -N "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/xxxxxx/${PWD##*/}/$1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as the command is being run inside the directory where you have the file, this should do it I suppose:

```
dirName=$(basename `pwd`)
wget -N "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/xxxxxx/${dirName}/file1.dat"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is better

```
wget -N "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/xxxxxx/$(basename `pwd`)/file1.dat"
```